# How to align two elements on the same line from PHP

Tags: html, css

Screenshots:
[Inspect element shows:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPJdf.png)
[The "7 in stock" i want to align with the "10" bellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLhDM.png)

I would like to align two `$elements` to display on the same line.

```
<span class="max">
    <?php echo $tickets_sold, $max_tickets; ?>
</span>
```

When the `$tickets_sold` is not included, the `$max_tickets` goes on the top. But when it's included, it immediately goes on the next line.

I've tried many different options as &&, and, but they never appear on the same line. I am sure the solution is easy, but I am a beginner.

```
$max_tickets = $product->get_max_tickets();
$tickets_sold = wc_get_stock_html( $product );
```

PHP code

```
 <div class="wcl-progress-meter <?php if($product->is_max_tickets_met()) echo 'full' ?>"> 
    <progress  max="<?php echo $max_tickets ?>" value="<?php echo $lottery_participants_count ?>"  low="<?php echo $min_tickets ?>"></progress></br> 
    <span class="zero">0 </span>
    <span class="max">  <?php echo $tickets_sold, $max_tickets?></div></span>
</div>
```

CSS file

```
.wcl-progress-meter meter::-webkit-meter-suboptimum-value {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -5px #999 inset;
  background: #cb132b;
  display:inline-block;

}

.wcl-progress-meter .zero {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -100%;
}

.wcl-progress-meter .min {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -100%;
}

.wcl-progress-meter .max {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -100%;
  right: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: This has to do with your HTML and CSS, not the PHP

Comment: this question can´t be answered without knowing which elements may be returned by '<?php echo $tickets_sold, $max_tickets?>' so you should add this. furthermore it´s a css related question not php. Do you use any css framework if so, which version?

Comment: it is located in the .php file responsible for showing the page

Comment: i think i don't use any css framework

Comment: PHP is server side and wont affect the layout. Only HTML and CSS will determine/ have an impact on the design. HTML and CSS can be put inside your PHP file, but it is still CSS related and not PHP

Comment: It seems to me that you have a forgotten closing `</div>` tag inside of the span element on fourth line.

Comment: Can you show us what PHP has rendered in the browser? As in what you can see if you inspect the element in the console?

Comment: I need at least 10 reputation to post images, so i let two links on the beginning of the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tweak your HTML a bit and all should work as you desire:

```
<style>
    .flex-parent{display:flex;}
    .flex-child{flex-basis:content;margin-right:10px;}
</style>
<div class="max flex-parent">
    <div class="flex-child"><?php echo $tickets_sold;?></div>
    <div class="flex-child"><?php echo $max_tickets;?></div>
</div>
```

```html
<style>
    .flex-parent{display:flex;}
    .flex-child{flex-basis:content;margin-right:10px;}
</style>
<div class="max flex-parent">
    <div class="flex-child">tickets_sold</div>
    <div class="flex-child">max_tickets</div>
</div>
```

---

Or, you could also just use display:inline:

```
<style>
    .inline-block{display:inline-block;margin-right:10px;}
</style>
<div class="max">
    <div class="inline-block"><?php echo $tickets_sold;?></div>
    <div class="inline-block"><?php echo $max_tickets;?></div>
</div>
```

```html
<style>
    .inline-block{display:inline-block;margin-right:10px;}
</style>
<div class="max">
    <div class="inline-block">tickets_sold</div>
    <div class="inline-block">max_tickets</div>
</div>
```

#### Update:

Note the change to the first example code - I neglected to add the `flex-parent` class *(a className I invented, not a convention)* to the `.max` div.

To center the items in the parent, add `justify-content:center;` to the parent:

```
<style>
    .flex-parent{display:flex;}
    .flex-child{flex-basis:content;margin-right:10px;justify-content:center;}
</style>
<div class="max flex-parent">
    <div class="flex-child"><?php echo $tickets_sold;?></div>
    <div class="flex-child"><?php echo $max_tickets;?></div>
</div>
```

---

Using the `display:inline-block` method:

```
<style>
    .inline-parent{text-align:center;}
    .inline-block{display:inline-block;margin-right:10px;}
</style>
<div class="max inline-parent">
    <div class="inline-block"><?php echo $tickets_sold;?></div>
    <div class="inline-block"><?php echo $max_tickets;?></div>
</div>
```

```html
    <style>
        .inline-parent{text-align:center;}
        .inline-block{display:inline-block;margin-right:10px;}
    </style>
    <div class="max inline-parent">
        <div class="inline-block">tickets_sold</div>
        <div class="inline-block">max_tickets</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the try, but the result is still the same - $tickets_sold stays on the top $max_tickets goes on the bottom as the screenshot from first line of the post

Comment: Did you add the style block above? Did you make your live code exactly what is in my answer? Or did you modify it somewhat? *(I am asking because sometimes people don't have the ability to modify HTML - we need to know that in order to answer the question)*

Comment: Okay i've let my wrong code and this was the problem, now after inputing only the both your ones it works absolutely fine ! THANK YOU SO MUCH ! Can you tell me how to center the $tickets_sold in middle ?

Comment: Are you using the `flexbox` method (the first example)?  Easy if you are.

Comment: No, I am using the '.inline-block' method since the flexbox not work for some reason.

Comment: Right, I found out why... *mea culpa*.  I'll update the answer again with the solution there also.  But flexbox is something you should learn. Here are two very helpful links:  [20min YouTube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k32voqQhODc) and [Excellent cheat sheet](https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/) - ***Very seriously, watch that tutorial. You will thank me later.***

Comment: First of all wanna say you are great! Thank you for the links! But for me the flex method doesn't work, do you know way to center the $tickets_sold in the middle with the second method (inline-block)?

Comment: At the very bottom of my answer (the 2nd item under "Update" - the one with the StackSnippet demo) - did you see that? Did it work for you? *(Basically, you need to add `text-align:center` to the parent container)*

Comment: I saw it and i test many times, but it moves only a bit it doesn't go to the center between MIN and MAX numbers :(

Comment: Okay, create another question and post your code. It would be great if you would also post (a) a screengrab of that HTML in the DOM (i.e. using F12 DevTools in Chrome *+ Windows Snipping Tool?*), and (b) a screenshot of how it looks on screen. *(Note that in the editor the 6th toolbar icon from left lets you post an image)* ***Then post a comment below this one with the URL of the new question***

Comment: Okay, i hope this time all looks a bit better - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56348745/how-to-change-place-of-elements-from-same-line