# How to change place of elements from same line

Tags: html, css

I have a block from 3 elements - minimum value, stock of a product, maximum value.

All i need to do is to find a way to align the stock of the product in the middle between both values.

My guess is that the problem should be somewhere on these lines:

```
<style>
    .inline-parent{text-align:center;}
    .inline-block{display:inline-block;margin-right:10px;}
</style>
<div class="max inline-parent">
    <div class="inline-block"><?php echo $tickets_sold;?></div>
    <div class="inline-block"><?php echo $max_tickets;?></div>
</div>
```

[My browser renders the file like this:(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woOYx.png)

[Inspect of the element shows this: (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2coty.png)

[Using Flex wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vVD3.png)
[even worst](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaQfd.png)

CSS -

```
.wcl-progress-meter meter::-webkit-meter-suboptimum-value {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -5px #999 inset;
  background: #cb132b;
  display:inline-block;

}


.wcl-progress-meter .zero {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -100%;
}

.wcl-progress-meter .min {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -100%;
}

.wcl-progress-meter .max {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -100%;
  right: 0;

}
```

PHP- file where i tried to edit the code

```
$max_tickets                = $product->get_max_tickets();
$tickets_sold    = wc_get_stock_html( $product );

<div class="wcl-progress-meter <?php if($product->is_max_tickets_met()) echo 'full' ?>"> 
               <progress  max="<?php echo $max_tickets ?>" value="<?php echo $lottery_participants_count ?>"  low="<?php echo $min_tickets ?>"></progress></br> 
                <span class="zero">0</span>
<style>
    .inline-parent{text-align:center;}
    .inline-block{display:inline-block;margin-right:10px;}
</style>
<div class="max inline-parent">
    <div class="inline-block"><?php echo $tickets_sold;?></div>
    <div class="inline-block"><?php echo $max_tickets;?></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Boyan - I don't understand the relationship between the 3 elements block (min/stock/max) and the tickets sold / max tickets block. What exactly is the problem -- is the progress meter displaying incorrectly? ***Or, do you need the `$stock_of_product`(?) to go between `$tickets_sold` and `$max_tickets` ?***

Comment: Where, in your question above, are you attempting to put the product stock?  *(Or, what needs to happen that isn't happening?)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS flexbox will help you achieve this easily.

[Check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/70cjvto8/)

[Read about CSS flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```
.value-container{
  width: 600px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

UPDATE:

Make sure you take out the span from **wcl-progress-meter** div and put it inside **max** div

You can also get rid  of **inline-block** class. Refer below Code.

```
 <span class="zero">0</span>
```

PHP:

```
<div class="max">
    <span class="zero">0</span>
    <div><?php echo $tickets_sold;?></div>
    <div><?php echo $max_tickets;?></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.max{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

UPDATE : 2 (Below CSS should work if you remove the absolute position)

```
.wcl-progress-meter meter::-webkit-meter-suboptimum-value {
   box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -5px #999 inset;
   background: #cb132b;
   display:inline-block;
 }

.wcl-progress-meter .zero {
 /* try removing the CSS */
}

.wcl-progress-meter .min {
/* try removing the CSS */
}

.wcl-progress-meter .max {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: I see on your example, works great! please tell me where is the place of this code in my CSS and how to call it in the PHP file which executes the script? ( i am totally new into all these languages  )

Comment: I follow your instructions, but for some reason, they appear one on the top of each other, not in line

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vVD3.png

Comment: You have to put the given css inside <style> tag in your page.

Comment: @BoyanMinev : make sure the class="zero" span is inside the max div and the given CSS is inside <style> tag in your php file.

Comment: Done it exactly as you said, don't understand where I am making the mistake

Comment: I can see your CSS the zero class is absolute. Try removing these CSS properties and see how the page looks.

Comment: You should try removing absolute css values from all the css classes and check the page. Basically the position absolute is wrong in your case.

Comment: i remove the properties and now drop just one line - https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaQfd.png

Comment: even tho i used " align-items: baseline; " in addition for the flex, doesn't work for some reason

Comment: Create a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) with complete PHP and CSS code for better understanding of DOM elements.

Comment: With more testing and deleting the formatting of the CSS it's worked! THANK YOU SO MUCH! You are the best!

Comment: @BoyanMinev : Glad you figured it out. Happy coding and Thanks :)